# Using While Loops inside a Command

Tags: autocad, autolisp

A simple loop program can be used as:

```
(setq y 0)
(while (< q 12) (setq q (1+ q)) 
(print "Hello")
)
```

But how to use such loops inside an Autocad command?

I believe the code below can be simplified using loops but how to use them inside a running command.

```
(defun PX (_angle)
  (list (* BaseRadius
       (+ (cos (+ 1.570796 _angle)) (* _angle (cos _angle)))
    )
    (* BaseRadius
       (+ (sin (+ 1.570796 _angle)) (* _angle (sin _angle)))
    )
  )
)

(defun c:cir ()
  (setq BaseRadius 8)
  (command "_pline"
       "qua"
       (PX 0)
       (PX 0.1)
       (PX 0.2)
       (PX 0.3)
       (PX 0.4)
       (PX 0.5)
       (PX 0.6)
       (PX 0.7)
       (PX 0.8)
       (PX 0.9)
       (PX 1)
       (PX 1.1)
       (PX 1.2)
       (PX 1.3)
       (PX 1.4)
       (PX 1.5)
       ""
  )
```

Comment: In your first example, I believe `(setq y 0)` should actually be `(setq q 0)`

Comment: Yes that must be corrected!

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways that you can accomplish this.

### Using `repeat`

The simplest method is likely to be the use of a `repeat` loop which evaluates a set of expressions a predetermined number of times, with your angle variable incremented with each iteration:

```lisp
(defun c:cir ( / ang rad )
    (setq ang 0.0
          rad 8.0
    )
    (command "_.pline")
    (repeat 16
        (command "_non"
            (list
                (* rad (+ (cos (+ (/ pi 2.0) ang)) (* ang (cos ang))))
                (* rad (+ (sin (+ (/ pi 2.0) ang)) (* ang (sin ang))))
            )
        )
        (setq ang (+ ang 0.1))
    )
    (command "")
    (princ)
)
```

#### Notes:

A few things to note regarding the above code:

- Local variables (i.e. variables that only need to be defined within the scope of this function) are declared as part of the `defun` expression, following the forward slash (`/`) in the arguments list. This ensures that variables defined by your function will not interfere with global variables of the same name defined in the Document namespace. For more information on this topic, you may wish to refer to my tutorial [here](http://lee-mac.com/localising.html).
- It is good practice to always use the underscore (`_`) & period (`.`) command prefixes (e.g. as in `"_.pline"`), as the underscore ensures that the English version of a command is always used, regardless of the language version of AutoCAD in which the function is evaluated; the period ensures that the original definition of the command is used, ignoring any possible redefinitions.
- The `"_non"` (or `"_none"`) Object Snap modifier supplied before any point input ensures that any active Object Snap modes are ignored when supplying the point to the command. An alternative is to temporarily store the value of the `OSMODE` system variable and set this to `0` (thus disabling all Object Snap modes) whilst supplying point input, or to temporarily set the `OSNAPCOORD` system variable to `1`, but either of these solutions necessitates the use of an error handler to reset the system variables should anything fail.
- The expressions `(cos (+ (/ pi 2.0) ang))` and `(sin (+ (/ pi 2.0) ang))` could optionally be replaced with `(sin (- ang))` and `(cos ang)` respectively. But I didn't want to stray too far from your original code, so that you could better understand the changes I have made.

### Using `while`

Alternatively, if you wish to iterate a number of times determined by the value of a variable exceeding a given limit, a `while` loop may be a more suitable option:

```lisp
(defun c:cir2 ( / ang rad )
    (setq ang 0.0
          rad 8.0
    )
    (command "_.pline")
    (while (< ang 1.6)
        (command "_non"
            (list
                (* rad (+ (sin (- ang)) (* ang (cos ang))))
                (* rad (+ (cos    ang)  (* ang (sin ang))))
            )
        )
        (setq ang (+ ang 0.1))
    )
    (command "")
    (princ)
)
```